# TeamCity and "net stop" command for deploy windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a TeamCity for automatic build and deploy of my window service. In build steps I have step with "net stop" command for stop windows service and replace files for this service. But in case of use my windows servie might be stopped already, and in this case TeamCity drop down deploy with error status. How can I avoid this?

Comment: which service do you want to stop? and how you start it later?

Comment: My windows service. of course. I use commands "net stop MyServiceName" and "net start MyServiceName"

Comment: I'm sorry. But I cannot catch what do you want to do. Could you please explain your problem?